# bootstrap dropdown inside ng repeat element hidden by overflow auto

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried turning overflow x off, changing the z-index, etc. but nothing seems to work for this antichrist code

nothing can go outside the box

The smaller boxes are generated by ngrepeat so I think something is not loading in order. Please help

Here's the jsfiddle for it but it's just the html code 
https://jsfiddle.net/5dbtb4h5/

```html
<div class="row containerrow">
  <!-- left column for upcoming -->
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 upcoming" style="background-color:yellow;">
    <p id="upcomingtitle">Upcoming</p>

    <div class="form-group updropdown">
      <select class="form-control" id="xyz">
    <option>All</option>
    <option>Checked In</option>
    <option>Not Checked In</option>
  </select>
    </div>
    <div class="upcominglist">
      <div class="upcomingtiles" ngdragclone="" ng-drag="true" ng-drag-success="$ctrl.testdrop()" ng-drag-data="appointment" ng-repeat="appointment in $ctrl.appointments" ng-if="appointment.StatusID == 0 || appointment.StatusID == 1">
        {{$ctrl.formatPatientInfo(appointment.DOB, appointment.DateTime, appointment.Gender, appointment.AppointmentTypeID)}}





        <div class="statusflag" ng-class="{'bluestatus' : appointment.StatusID > 0, 'emptystatus' : appointment.StatusID == 0}"></div>
        <div class="uptext"> <span class="boldtitle">{{appointment.FirstName}} {{appointment.LastName}}, {{$ctrl.year - $ctrl.patientYear}}, {{$ctrl.gender}}</span><br/> {{$ctrl.signInTime}} {{$ctrl.patientAppointmentType}} <br/> {{appointment.Complaint}}
        </div>


        <div class="dropdown dropdown1">
          <img class="dropdownarrow dropdown-toggle" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown" src="/images/transarrow.png">

          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu1 dropdown-menu-right">
            <li role="presentation"><a ng-click="$ctrl.updateAppointmentStatus(appointment, 0)">Not Checked In</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a ng-click="$ctrl.updateAppointmentStatus(appointment, 1)">Checked In</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a ng-click="$ctrl.onClickStoreAppointment(appointment); $ctrl.on()">Move to Room</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>



      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- end right column -->

</div>
<!-- end container row -->
```

[image: screenshot here]

Comment: could you provide us with your code and css... or jsfiddle ... we can then help you better

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: @HimanshuBansal hello, I added the html code of the yellow box only. I can't figure out how to get the draggable patient boxes out of the yellow box. Also, the dropdown is still cut off so I think all the elements inside the ngrepeat are just stuck in there. Please help me

Comment: @Amanda can you provide the css too... and if you can update this https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/4/ fiddle with workable code.. i or someone else might be able to help you :) Couldn't replicate the same issue here